# What are the possible dimensions of $ \ P_1 \cap P_2 \ $?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ P_1 \ \ and \ \ P_2 \ $ be two hyperplanes of $ \ \mathbb{R}^4 \ $ and  $ \ P_1 \cap P_2 \ $  is also a hyperplane in $ \ \mathbb{R}^4 \ $ .

What are the possible dimensions  of $ \ P_1 \cap P_2 \ $ ?

**Answer:**

Since $ P_1 \cap P_2 \ $ is also a hyperplane in $ \mathbb{R}^4 \ $ ,  $ dim (P_1 \cap P_2 )=3 \ $ .

But in addition $ dim (P_1 \cap P_2 ) \in \{0,1,2,3 \} \ $ .

For,

2 different planes forms a 2-dimensional hyper plane in $ \mathbb{R}^4 \ $.

3 different lines forms a 1-dimensional hyperplane in $ \mathbb{R}^4 \ $.

4 different planes not passing through origin  $0  $ forms a 0-dimensional hyperplane .

**But I am not sure.**

**I need confirmation of my work . If I am wrong then how can I solve the problem ?**

Comment: If $P_1 \cap P_2 \subset P_1$, and both have the same dimension since they are hyperplanes, what can you say?

Comment: So $ dim (P_1 \cap P_2)=3 $

Comment: Yes, that follows from the fact that $P_1 \cap P_2$ is also a hyperplane. But here, we  are saying that one hyperplane is contained in another hyperplane. When does this happen?